# How to remove duplicate pair values from given array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to remove a pair of 'duplicates' from an array of strings, where each element has the form `R1,R2`, with varying numbers. In my case, a duplicate would be `R2,R1` because it has the same elements of `R1,R2` but inverted.

Given:

```rb
a = ['R1,R2', 'R3,R4', 'R2,R1', 'R5,R6']
```

The resulting array should be like so:

```rb
a = ['R1,R2', 'R3,R4', 'R5,R6']
```

How could I remove the duplicates so I would have the following?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution with `Set`

```rb
require 'set' 

a.uniq { |item| Set.new(item.split(",")) }  # => ["R1,R2", "R3,R4", "R5,R6"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working example :

```
array = ['R1,R2', 'R3,R4', 'R2,R1', 'R5,R6']

array.uniq { |a| a.split(',').sort }
```

Comment: You can shorten this to `array.uniq {|a| a.split(',').sort.join(',') }`.

Comment: Why do you need the `join`? It works even without that :)

Comment: You are right :) It was a leftover from the initial answer.

Comment: @Ursus the desired output in the question is a array of strings - not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
def unique(array)
    pure = Array.new
    for i in array
        flag = false
        for j in pure
            flag = true if (j.split(",").sort == i.split(",").sort)
        end
        pure << i unless flag
    end
    return pure
end
```

reference: https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Remove_duplicate_elements#Ruby

Comment: I don't mean this as an insult but the solution you provided is very non-idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements of your array are "pairs", they should maybe be *actual* pairs and not strings, like this:

```
pairs = [['R1', 'R2'], ['R3', 'R4'], ['R2', 'R1'], ['R5', 'R6']]
```

And, in fact, since order doesn't seem to matter, it looks like they *really* should be sets:

```
require 'set'

sets = [Set['R1', 'R2'], Set['R3', 'R4'], Set['R2', 'R1'], Set['R5', 'R6']]
```

If that is the case, then `Array#uniq` will simply work as expected:

```
sets.uniq
#=> [#<Set: {"R1", "R2"}>, #<Set: {"R3", "R4"}>, #<Set: {"R5", "R6"}>]
```

So, the best way would be to change the code that produces this value to return an array of two-element sets.

If that is not possible, then you should transform the value at your system boundary when it enters the system, something like this:

```
sets = a.map {|el| el.split(',') }.map(&Set.method(:new))
```

Comment: That doesn't really solves what OP posted, since you actually modified the specification of the problem.

Comment: @oxfist the recommendation to transform the values into actual sets is spot on though.